# Link to xml file searching for the file in the wrong place

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Hi I seem to be having some problems when working with linq to xml.When I try to load the xml file in my code it seems LINQ is looking for it in C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express.

This is my code:

```
public static class ConfigurationData
{
    public static string GetAssemblyName()
    {
        var assemblyName = from config in XDocument.Load(@"T4Config.xml").Descendants("dataService")
                           select config.Element("AssemblyProjectName").Value; 


        if (assemblyName != null)
        {
            return assemblyName.ToString();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Both the XML file and this class are in a folder called Controller details.When I try to load this method I get a file not found exception , BEcause linq is searching in C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express.

How can I make linq look for it in the same foldeR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var assemblyName = from config in XDocument.Load(@"T4Config.xml").Descendants("dataService")
                           select config.Element("AssemblyProjectName").Value;
```

I am not sure how this is even getting to the folder you mentioned, as you have only specified a file name. Change `XDocument.Load("file.xml")` too `XDocument.Load("YourFolder\YourSubFolder\YourFile.xml`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Server.MapPath("/T4Config.xml")`